# TensorFlow data set when split to train test and validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

im currently developing speaker recognition using cnn.

my dataset contains spectrogram images I load it through datagen.flow_from_directory(

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\dataset\dataset\XXX\audio-imagesH",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)

valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\dataset\dataset\XXX\audio-imagesH",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset='validation',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
```

which will result in a tf data set procced on the fly to prevent memory issues

my question here

```
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\dataset\dataset\XXX\audio-imagesTest",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",  
    shuffle=False
)
```

when I load my test dataset which is a new unseen data that not included in the train dataset ,  the argument class_mode will load the labels for each file but the question is if we load the test with the labels and then predict on the model does it as i'm cheating and feed the model the test with their labels ? or the predict argument ignore the labels and predict on the model ?

because when I set class_mode=None which will not load the labels and predict it give me 0
but when I load the labels with it shows 97% which is seems right because the model accuracy on training and validation 99%

Answer (score 0):

The field `class_mode` will not be used at all during the execution of the `predict()` method. But you need to generate your test data with it, to get labels, in order to compare these labels with the results of the prediction and compute a score.